# Query not showing results after passing parameters from frontend?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, express, axios

I am passing a search parameter from my React front end to my mySQL Express backend. My hardcoded query works, but when I try to pass in the parameter my code DOESNT catch an error but it also doesnt load any data to the url.

Front end component:

```
    handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setState(e.target.value);
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/data", {params: {state:state}})
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("successful GET");
        })
    }
```

Router on the back end:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next)=>{
    let state = req.query.state;

    try{
        let results = await mysqldb.getCities(state);
        res.json(results);
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});
```

db on the back end:

```
let mysqldb = {};

mysqldb.getCities = (state) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        conn.query("SELECT city FROM states_city WHERE state_name=? ORDER BY city", [state], (err, results)=>{
            if(err){
                return console.log(err);
            }else{
                console.log("queried succesful " + state);
                return resolve(results);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you `console.log()` `results` variable ?

Comment: Oh, I get "RowDataPacket { city: namehere }", so it is getting the results, but the json isnt being shown on the url? and what is rowdatapacket?

Answer (score 0):

`RowDataPacket` is the name of the constructor function that created the object returned by `await mysqldb.getCities(state);`.

You can convert and send it back as a regular object by:

```
let results = await mysqldb.getCities(state);
results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
res.json(results);
```

Comment: When i console log the new results, I get the correct response format, but when I go to the url, there is no data still.

Comment: @LatePayment I caught a typo in my answer. I had `result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));` instead of `results = ...`. If you copied and pasted, that may be the issue. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: yeah i saw the typo and assumed so, unfortunately it doesnt seem to be the issue. just empty [] when i load the url.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated route for `/api/data`? I gotta ask because of the disparity between `/api/data` and `/`. I guess I am just asking to make sure you're accessing the right URL.

Comment: yeah I do, like i mentioned in my post my query and link work fine when I hardcode the query. Issues only come up when I pass my axios parameters.